# python compare elements in alist of tuples with the same index

Tags: python

I have a list of tuples :

```
list = [(u'RHSA-2017:1270', u'Red Hat Enterprise Linux 6'), (u'RHSA-2017:1271', u'Red Hat Enterprise Linux 6'), (u'RHSA-2017:1270', u'Red Hat Enterprise Linux 7')]
```

i need to  compare index1 element for each tuple i.e

```
'Red Hat Enterprise Linux 6'
```

which is the same for the first 2 tuples

and the first index element in tuple 3 ,which is :

```
'Red Hat Enterprise Linux 7'
```

my goal is once i detected that element index 1 in tuple 2 is duplicate

remove this tuple from the list.

i have tried to create anew list with the required tuples by i am getting

an empty list

```
new_list = []
for i in list:
    rhel_ver = str(i[1])
    if rhel_ver not in i:
         new_list.append(i)
```

getting empty list. how can i get only the first tuple that contains
the rhel version ,i.e:

```
list = [(u'RHSA-2017:1270', u'Red Hat Enterprise Linux 6'), (u'RHSA-2017:1270', u'Red Hat Enterprise Linux 7')]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `any` built-in to make a new unique list:

```
my_list = [(u'RHSA-2017:1270', u'Red Hat Enterprise Linux 6'), (u'RHSA-2017:1271', u'Red Hat Enterprise Linux 6'),
           (u'RHSA-2017:1270', u'Red Hat Enterprise Linux 7')]

unique_list = []
for element in my_list:
    if not any(tup[1] == element[1] for tup in unique_list):
        unique_list.append(element)

print(unique_list)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can keep track of the elements you've already seen in a `set`:

```
lst = [(u'RHSA-2017:1270', u'Red Hat Enterprise Linux 6'), 
       (u'RHSA-2017:1271', u'Red Hat Enterprise Linux 6'), 
       (u'RHSA-2017:1270', u'Red Hat Enterprise Linux 7')]
seen = set()
result = []
for rhsa, name in lst:
    if name not in seen:
        result.append((rhsa, name))
        seen.add(name)
print(result)
# [('RHSA-2017:1270', 'Red Hat Enterprise Linux 6'), ('RHSA-2017:1270', 'Red Hat Enterprise Linux 7')]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use python OrderedDict to create a new list setting the index 1 (second element in the tuple) as key. This will remove any duplicate. You can then produce a new list from the Ordered Dict. python 2.7

```
import collections
tagPairs=collections.OrderedDict()

lst = [(u'RHSA-2017:1270', u'Red Hat Enterprise Linux 6'), 
       (u'RHSA-2017:1271', u'Red Hat Enterprise Linux 6'), 
       (u'RHSA-2017:1270', u'Red Hat Enterprise Linux 7')]
for i,v in lst:
    tagPairs[v]=i
unique_list=[]
for k,j in tagPairs.items():
    unique_list.append((j,k))
print unique_list
```

Comment: I think OP wanted to keep the first element for any unique key, but you can fix this by using `for i,v in reversed(lst)`. Also, the last part could be done shorter with a list comprehension (or just do `tagPairs[v] = (i,v)` and then `unique_list = list(tagPairs.items())`)